# Why Are My Checkbox Values Empty on Reform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reform

Using Reform - I am trying to pass a collection of checkboxes to my form class so I can do something with it. But the collection is `nil` every time.

Here is ***part*** of my view;

```
<%= simple_form_for @form, url: the_update_path(
  @programme
) do |f| %>

  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(
    :current_case_worker_ids,
    @sponsor_case_workers,
    :id,
    :full_name,
    checked: f.object.model.case_worker_ids
  ) %>
```

Here is my form class;

```
class ProgrammeCaseWorkersForm < ApplicationForm
  property :case_worker_ids
  property :current_case_worker_ids, virtual: true

  def case_worker_ids=(case_worker_ids)
    binding.pry
```

When I inspect `current_case_worker_ids` in binding.pry - it's `nil`. Why?

The boxes look checked on the form. And here is the HTML markup of one of the checkboxes;

```
<span>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked" name="programme_case_workers[current_case_worker_ids][]" id="programme_case_workers_current_case_worker_ids_2">
<label class="collection_check_boxes" for="programme_case_workers_current_case_worker_ids_2">Mose Spinka</label>
</span>
```